# How do I include JavaScript with assets (libraries.yml)?

Tags: 8, javascript

This is my `mytheme.libraries.yml` file:

```
global-styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}

  js:
      js/effect.js: {}
    dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

This is my `js/effect.js` file:

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
      alert("Hello World");
  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

I created jquery.js in core folder of my site root.
Even if I remove the  dependency line from my libraries.yml and remove jquery syntax from my effect.js, I receive nothing on my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most times it's about blanks. The yml files are very picky about this. Looks like your effects.js has 6 blanks instead of four.

And make sure, that you have your global-styling listed in the libraries section of your theme.info.yml.

Comment: Thank You !!! I was not writing global-styling in my theme.info.yml. It works now, kudos to you man ! Anyways, can you tell me what is blanks you told, in yml files ?

Comment: Your line `js/effect.js: {}` has six spaces before `js`. It should only have four.

Comment: @MarkConroy does it goes for css/style.css too?

Comment: @ReesGargi In the case you have above, no. As that is indented under `theme` which has four spaces. See here: https://www.drupal.org/coding-standards/config#whitespace